# Gitlab api V4 only utilizing one of the parameters I am sending

Tags: curl, gitlab, gitlab-api

Whichever parameter I send first is the one that is utilized. The rest are ignored. If you look at the paging information below, you will see how this plays out. Why does the gitlab api V4 only respect the first parameter and ignore the rest?

```
$ curl --head --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: asdfasdf" https://gitlab.asdfasdf.com/api/v4/projects/?per_page=100&page=2

RESPONSE HEADERS
x-next-page: 2
x-page: 1
x-per-page: 100
x-prev-page:
x-total: 172
x-total-pages: 2


$ curl --head --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: asdfasdf" https://gitlab.asdfasdf.com/api/v4/projects/?per_page=50&page=2

RESPONSE HEADERS
x-next-page: 2
x-page: 1
x-per-page: 50
x-prev-page: 
x-total: 172
x-total-pages: 4


$ curl --head --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: asdfasdf" https://gitlab.asdfasdf.com/api/v4/projects?page=2

RESPONSE HEADERS
x-next-page: 3
x-page: 2
x-per-page: 20
x-prev-page: 1
x-total: 172
x-total-pages: 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose the URL with quotes `"` as the question mark `?`  is treat as wildcard or the ampersand `&` will send the command to the background depending on your shell.

```
curl --head --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: asdfasdf" "https://gitlab.asdfasdf.com/api/v4/projects?page=2"

RESPONSE HEADERS
…
X-Page: 2
…
```